# Can I assign an index to an exploded array?

Tags: json, array, hiveql

I'm doing a `LATERAL EXPLODE` on an array in Hive, is there a way of reliably assigning a row number based on the array element? It looks like calling `row_number()` on the results of the `LATERAL EXPLODE` works, but I don't know if that is dependable.

It does seem to be in practice. We're doing this now and have never encountered a case where the elements have been enumerated incorrectly.